# Has any one Used DMO in C#?

Tags: c#, directx, directshow, dmo

Has any one Used DMO (Microsoft DirectX Media Objects) in C#? **Not using DShow.**
Any Libs, Wrapers, etc?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I personally am not familiar with that framework, but does [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/) support it?

Comment: at least it supports Dx Objects so probably Yes it can=) Thank U WWmuch.